# Pandas sort values based on distinct values, rather than counts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Output below is sorted by counts. I want it sorted by values in alphabetic order. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

```
df['Item_Type'].value_counts(dropna=False).sort_values(ascending=True, na_position='first')
```

Comment: Use `sort_index`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `sort_index`, not `sort_values`

When you call `value_counts` you get back a new data frame where the index is the unique values of the column and the first value column is the counts.

Comment: Thanks Lou. Sort Index did the trick.